# Two CSS animations targeting the same div won't work on Chrome but works fine on Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

I have the following markup and CSS. The button is affected by two CSS animations: A bounceIn animation when the button is rendered and a hover effect.

My problem is that this works fine in Safari, but doesn't work in Chrome. Chrome seems to ignore the **transform** rule in the `:hover` pseudo class because of the bounceIn animation. If I remove the following classes: **animated-second bounceInUp** , the hover state works. Any ideas?

```css
.ico-btn.blue-stroke {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 10px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
  border-left-color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 10px;
}
.ico-btn.btn-settings-smm-txt {
  font-family: 'webfontregular', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 15px;
  min-width: 0px;
  padding: 60px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 140px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
}
.ico-btn {
  margin-right: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .1s ease-out;
  transition: transform .1s ease-out;
}
.ico-btn:hover,
.ico-btn:active,
.ico-btn-android {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.92);
  transform: scale(0.92);
  opacity: 0.80;
  color: #89df88;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.animated-second {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes bounceInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.bounceInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
  animation-name: bounceInUp;
}
```

```html
<div role="button" class="ico-btn btn-settings-smm-txt blue-stroke campaign-button animated-second bounceInUp">
  <span>A</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I am on chrome and hover is working for me :-/

Comment: I'm on Chrome too, and for me the transition doesn't work

Comment: I'm on Chrome and it's working fine for me. Have you checked you're using an up to date version of Chrome? That could be your issue potentially

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm using Chrome in Mac and it is up to date. I am using my markup for a Phonegap app and it doesn't work in the Android emulator which uses Chrome either. Strangely, it doesn't work on Firefox either. Odd

Comment: @user1038814 I know what's causing the problem and how to fix it (set `animation-fill-mode: none` instead of `both` and both works) but I don't know why it works. If you still wish to have it as an answer, I will post this comment as one.

Comment: @Harry Thanks for that Harry, it worked! Bizarre, I'm not sure why it does either. Anyway, happy to accept your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (for some reason unknown to me) seems to be because of `animation-fill-mode: both` setting for the `.animated-second` selector. Setting it as `animation-fill-mode: none` seems to solve the problem.

The only explanation that I could think of is that [`animation-fill-mode: both`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#valdef-animation-fill-mode-both) makes the element hold the state as of the last keyframe once the animation is completed and since the last keyframe has a `transform` setting it is somehow preventing the scale from being applied whereas when the fill mode is set to `none`, the element has no `transform` once the animation is complete.

Setting [`animation-fill-mode: backwards`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#valdef-animation-fill-mode-backwards) also gets the scale transform working and since this is also similar to `animation-fill-mode` (in the sense that it doesn't make the element hold the transform), it kind of proves the above point.

(*I am trying to find the exact reason and will edit it in when I find it or will remove my answer if a better one is posted.*)

```css
.ico-btn.blue-stroke {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 10px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
  border-left-color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 10px;
}
.ico-btn.btn-settings-smm-txt {
  font-family: 'webfontregular', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 15px;
  min-width: 0px;
  padding: 60px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 140px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: rgb(52, 152, 219);
}
.ico-btn {
  margin-right: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .1s ease-out;
  transition: transform .1s ease-out;
}
.ico-btn:hover,
.ico-btn:active,
.ico-btn-android {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.92);
  transform: scale(0.92);
  opacity: 0.80;
  color: #89df88;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.animated-second {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
  animation-fill-mode: none;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes bounceInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.bounceInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
  animation-name: bounceInUp;
}
```

```html
<div role="button" class="ico-btn btn-settings-smm-txt blue-stroke campaign-button animated-second bounceInUp">
  <span>A</span>
</div>
```